# Custom cursor adapter not showing anything

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have a list activity that has a TextView and EditText field per row. Previously I was using simplecursoradapter but to get around the problem of getting values from EditText and using in other activities. As well as recycling moving user inputs around I'm trying to move to a custom one. I've got it to run but when it does it does not display any of my results. At this point its just showing my footer at the bottom.

// custom adapter

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, layout);
        this.cursor = cursor;
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected EditText edittext;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_row, null);


             holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
            holder.edittext = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int label_index = cursor.getColumnIndex("userword"); 
        String label = cursor.getString(label_index);


        holder.text.setText(label);




        return convertView;
    }
}
```

//My list activity

```
public class editview extends ListActivity {
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();


        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
        showResults();
        }


    private void showResults (){
        Cursor cursor = mydbhelper.getUserWord();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_USERWORD};
         int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textType};
         ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.edit_row, cursor,
                        from, to);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
            //footer button
            public void onClick(View footer){
                    final MediaPlayer editClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
                    editClickSound.start();

                }
        }
```

//My cursor located in dbadapter class

```
    // retrieves all the descriptions for the edittext fields
      public  Cursor getUserWord() 
        {
            return myDataBase.query(USER_WORD_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ID, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY,
                    KEY_SOURCE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_USERWORD, KEY_QUICK 
                    }, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY+ "=" + categories.categoryClick + " AND " + KEY_SOURCE+ "=" 
                    +source.sourceClick + " AND " + KEY_TITLE+ "=" + title.titleClick, 
                    null, null, null, KEY_ID);

        }
```

To give more info on how this works. User will got through a series of Listviews, category->source->title. Then brings them to this activity with the EditText where I will take their inputs and use them in the next activity. I'm pretty new to the custom cursor adapter since I'm new to android and still learning so I'm having trouble understanding what I'm missing.

Comment: What am I missing here then? I based this off of http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834102/cursor-and-adapter and http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict/SearchableDictionary.html your comment doesn't really help.

Comment: Well I figured it out. After looking at it with fresh eyes I say I forget to change extends ArrayAdapter<Model>. I was building this off a Arrayadapter I built for learning purposes. Not sure why above comment didn't just point that out.